# Textarea doesnt start top left

Tags: html

I have two issues that are occurring, the place holder will not appear and whenever I click on my textarea, it starts typing from where I clicked instead of the top left?

```css
textarea {
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  text-align: start;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="70" rows="4" placeholder="Adding a rich description will help with the search result">
                </textarea>
```

Comment: Perfect example on why a placeholder is no replacement for a label :-D

Answer (score 1):

A placeholder will only appear if there is no content in the textarea.

You have set default content of "a bunch of spaces and a new line".

Remove the content between `>` and `<`.